# Trailing Blanks SAS

Tags: sas

I am attempting to clean some data. Under a variable 'Education Level' I have multiple observations referring to holding a master's degree. Eg. "Masters" "Masters Degree" "Master's Degree". I have organized these into one value: "Masters Degree" using IF-THEN statements. However, I have another entry with trailing blanks named "Masters Degree  " that isn't being picked up by the IF-THEN statements. How can I trim this down?

I've researched some functions to deal with this such as TRIM() but I don't really understand how I can implement these as I am new to SAS.

This is how I have been attempting to tidy my data and format I have used for the previous variables:

```
data libref.name;
  set libref.name;

  if Var1 = "Masters" then Var1 = "Masters Degree";

  if Var1 = "Master's" then Var1 = "Masters Degree";

  if Var1 = "Master Degree  " then Var1 = "Masters Degree";    
run;
```

I simply want to convert "Master Degree  " observations into "Masters Degree"

Comment: Is your LIBREF pointing at a foreign database? Like ORACLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert everything that begins with "Master", then use the `:` operator after `=`, which works like a wildcard.

`if Var1 =: "Master" then V22 = "Masters Degree"`

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: LukeBirkett it's good you gave feedback, you should also be able to accept @Longfish's response as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

That can't be the Problem because "Master Degree " is same as "Master Degree"

```
data _NULL_;
    if "Master Degree " = "Master Degree" then put "EQUAL";
    else put "DIFFERENT";
run;
```

Will output:

```
8    data _NULL_;
9        if "Master Degree " = "Master Degree" then put "EQUAL";
10       else put "DIFFERENT";
11   run;

EQUAL
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

That is because SAS ignores any trailing blanks by comparison. And that is because SAS will append trailing blanks when ever you string to an variable that is shorter than that variable.

However you said the other one is "Masters Degree" and thats different from "Master Degree"

Comment: I know you've mentioned it, but might be worth explicitly highlighting that one "Master" has an "s" after it, since they missed it in their own testing then they might also miss it in your answer (or even for any subsequent reader).

Comment: I made a few typos which probably confused things. When using PROC FREQ "Master Degree" and "Master Degree  " were definitely picked up as two different things, and within IF statements identical observations but with trailing blanks would not pick up each other, e.g. IF "High School" would not pick with "High School  ". In the end, I used =: capture all similar observations at once

Comment: In that case the space is not a space. It could be any character that does not display. Such as tab '09'x, linefeed '0A'x. carriage return '0D'x, null '00'x or non-breaking space 'A0'x.

Comment: Do you have a link to an official source about ignoring trailing blanks when comparing strings?  I've seen that fact mentioned a number of times, but can't seem to locate it in the SAS documentation.